# How to mark certain point in ggpairs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, ggpairs

Here's minimal working problem. Consider the following data frame

```
DF <- data.frame(
  y=1:10,
  x=10:1,
  z=rep(5,10),
  a=11:20
)
```

Assume `y` is my response. Now, for every pair plot `(y,_)` in `ggpairs(DF)` I want to mark point 1, 5 and 10 with a different color. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an in-built way of doing this in `ggpairs`. There is a way round it, which is to modify the plot it produces. Of necessity, this is a "hacky" solution. It first requires you to specify the points panels (i.e. the ones you wish to modify), and of course the rows whose points you wish to be red:

```r
point_panels <- c(5, 9, 10, 11, 13:15)
red_points <- c(1, 5, 10)
```

If you have done that correctly, the following code should transform your plots appropriately:

```r
ggp <- ggpairs(DF)
ggp$data$colors <- "normal"
ggp$data$colors[red_points] <- "special"

for(i in point_panels) {
  ggp$plots[[i]]$mapping <- 
    `class<-`(c(ggp$plots[[i]]$mapping, aes(color = colors)), "uneval")
}

ggp <- ggp + scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```

So now when we do:

```
ggp
```

we get

[image]

If you want to add a legend, do

```r
ggp$legend <- point_panels[1]
ggp
```

[image]